# I have a problem with displaying a simple screen in OpenGL

Tags: c++

Basically I was following the tutorial on YouTube about working with OpenGL. 
I wrote the author's code there, but when I tried to run it gave me an error like:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x350) at `glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );`

Also it gives me the error of Target Integrity.

How can I fix this?

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
//GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

//GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OPENGL", nullptr, nullptr );
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );

    if ( nullptr  == window )
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to create GLWwindow"<<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate( );

        return 0;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit() )
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to initialize GLEW"<<std::endl;

        return 0;
    }

    glViewport( 0,0, screenWidth, screenHeight );

    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3, 1.0f);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;

}
`
```

Comment: A quick diagnostic test you could try: move the line with `glfwGetFramebufferSize` down so that it is right before the line with `glfwMakeContextCurrent`. (The real goal is to have it after the null check.)

Comment: So now it says instead that is failed to create GLWWindow

Comment: Excellent. You now know that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is just a symptom of `glfwCreateWindow` returning a null pointer. You can now refocus your question on the root cause. *(Also, you might want to question the reliability of a video that fails to have the null check **before** using the pointer.)*

Answer (score 0):

In

```
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
```

Try change the second line to:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```